# Issues with apt-get update command

Tags: linux, operating-system, debian

When I try to run the command `sudo apt-get update` I get the following:

```
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release.gpg                                 
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release                                      
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources/DiffIndex                       
Ign http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie InRelease                                            
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie InRelease                                           
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Sources/DiffIndex                                          
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease                                                         
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie InRelease                                                                       
Hit http://debmon.org debmon-jessie InRelease                                              
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free Sources/DiffIndex                                            
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release.gpg                                                               
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease                                                               
Ign http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie Release.gpg                                          
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                                   
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates Release.gpg                                                       
Ign http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie Release                                                                    
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free amd64 Packages/DiffIndex            
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release                                                                   
Hit http://ftp.debian.org jessie Release.gpg                                                                     
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-updates Release.gpg                                       
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates Release                                     
Hit http://debmon.org debmon-jessie/main amd64 Packages                                    
Ign http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie/all Sources/DiffIndex                                                                     
Ign http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie/all amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                                                
Hit http://ftp.debian.org jessie Release                                                                          
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-updates Release                                                                                        
Ign http://debmon.org debmon-jessie/main Translation-en_NZ                                                        
Ign http://debmon.org debmon-jessie/main Translation-en                                                           
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-updates/main Sources/DiffIndex                                                                                                                                                   
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-updates/contrib Sources/DiffIndex                                                                                                                                                
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-updates/non-free Sources/DiffIndex                                                                                                                                               
Get:1 http://ftp.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex [6,916 B]                                                                                                                                
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-updates/contrib amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                                                                                                                                         
Get:2 http://ftp.debian.org jessie-updates/non-free amd64 Packages/DiffIndex [736 B]                                                                                                                              
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Translation-en_NZ                                                                                                                                           
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Translation-en                                                                                                                                              
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en_NZ                                                                                                                                              
Ign http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie/all Translation-en_NZ                                                                                                                                                       
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en                                                                                                                                                 
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free Translation-en_NZ                                                                                                                                          
Hit http://ftp.debian.org jessie/main Sources                                                                                                                                                                     
Ign http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie/all Translation-en                                                                                                                                                          
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free Translation-en                                                                                                                                             
Hit http://ftp.debian.org jessie/contrib Sources                                                                                                                                                                  
Err http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie/all Sources                                                                                                                                                                 
  503  OUT OF DISK SPACE
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources                                                                                                                                                        
  404  Not Found
Hit http://ftp.debian.org jessie/non-free Sources                                                                                                                                                                 
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Sources                                                                                                                                                     
  404  Not Found
Hit http://ftp.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                                                                              
Hit http://ftp.debian.org jessie/contrib amd64 Packages                                                                                                                                                           
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free Sources                                                                                                                                                    
  404  Not Found
Err http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie/all amd64 Packages                                                                                                                                                          
  503  OUT OF DISK SPACE
Hit http://ftp.debian.org jessie/non-free amd64 Packages                                                                                                                                                          
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                                                                 
  404  Not Found
Hit http://ftp.debian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en                                                                                                                                                           
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib amd64 Packages                                                                                                                                              
  404  Not Found
Hit http://ftp.debian.org jessie/main Translation-en                                                                                                                                                              
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free amd64 Packages                                                                                                                                             
  404  Not Found
Hit http://ftp.debian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en                                                                                                                                                          
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-updates/contrib Translation-en_NZ                                                                                                                                                
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-updates/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-updates/main Translation-en_NZ
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-updates/non-free Translation-en_NZ
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-updates/non-free Translation-en
Err http://ftp.debian.org jessie-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ftp.debian.org jessie-updates/contrib Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ftp.debian.org jessie-updates/non-free Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ftp.debian.org jessie-updates/contrib amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/contrib amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/non-free amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en_NZ
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main Translation-en_NZ
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main Translation-en
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en_NZ
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/contrib amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/non-free amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/contrib Translation-en_NZ
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main Translation-en_NZ
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/non-free Translation-en_NZ
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/non-free Translation-en
Fetched 7,652 B in 58s (130 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/contrib/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/non-free/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.dotdeb.org/dists/jessie/all/source/Sources  503  OUT OF DISK SPACE

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.dotdeb.org/dists/jessie/all/binary-amd64/Packages  503  OUT OF DISK SPACE

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/contrib/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/non-free/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Also, I accidentally removed php5 packages and now I am unable to install them back, I think the problem of why I cannot install the missing packages is caused by not being able to successfully run the apt-get.
I am using Linux Debian Jessie v8

Any help please,
Thank you: :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem and below I post a step by step guide of how I solved it:

1. Make sure that any third party repositories used by the system are disabled by commenting them out from inside /etc/apt/sources.list.d/{thirdpartyfilename.list}
2. Make sure the file /etc/apt/sources.list has the correct valid sources list if you are not sure of how to generate a valid sources list you can use a generator through this website https://debgen.simplylinux.ch/ by just entering the Location, the release of the software you are using (e.g. Debian Jessie), and make sure to tick all the boxes for the Debian Branches and Debian updates
3. Often times the sources list could be not up to date so changing the location of the source to a different country's server may actually make it work. E.g. http://ftp.debian.org may give broken results so changing it to http://ftp.au.debian.org or http://ftp.us.debian.org may make it work
4. Fixing the source list 404 not found error means now you should be able to patch your system by running the command **sudo apt-get update** and as a result be able to install any missing or broken packages (Unmet Dependencies) simply by running the command **sudo apt-get -f install**